# how to show popover menu when hover on link and popover itself

Tags: jquery, css

I got a problem when I make link with popover.
When mouse out of link but hover at popover I want to stay popover. 
and if mouse out of link icon and not in popover area then the popover is hidden.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d92gzl955 when hove it shows popover as follow image.http://awesomescreenshot.com/06e2gzlbdc

How can I do? right now im using jQuery .hover(function(){}, function()}); but can't fix. 
Please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste here your some of related code blocks (HTML + JS)?

Comment: here's the code : http://jsfiddle.net/a9xND/

Comment: here's my code jsfiddle.net/a9xND

    .popover{
        display:block;
        top: 66px;
        left: 70px;
        display:none;
    }

    ... jQuery ...

    $('a').hover(function(){
    
       $('.popover').css({ 
        display: 'block'
       });
    }, function(){
        $('.popover').hover(function(){   
        }, function(){
            $('.popover').css({ 
                display: 'none'
            });
        });
    });

Please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be more useful than those screenshots, but you should put both the link and the popover inside a common container and set the hover listener on that container. That way if you're hovering the link or hovering the popover, you'd also be hovering the container element, and your popover will remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the icon and popup item should wrap up with a common TAG for better performance. In my case, LI tag is applied. And in jQuery, this parent LI tag is used to write for hover events.

HTML:

```
<ul class="iconsWrap">
<li class="iconItem">
    <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></a>
    <div class="popover bottom">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Korea</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pakistan</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="iconItem">
    <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></a>
    <div class="popover bottom">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Korea</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pakistan</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="iconItem">
    <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></a>
    <div class="popover bottom">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Korea</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pakistan</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 40px 0 0 100px;
}
i{
    font-size: 26px;
}
.popover{
    display:block;
    top: 25px;
    left: -28px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.iconsWrap{}
li.iconItem{display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; position:relative}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('li.iconItem').hover(
        function(){
            $('.popover',this).css({display: 'block'});
        },
        function(){
            $('.popover',this).css({display: 'none'});
        }
    );
});
```

Please see this LIVE: [jsfiddle.net/mamun_reza/a9xND/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mamun_reza/a9xND/2/) . Let me know if you have any more questions regarding this issue :)